# Command availability with multiple officers on base defense

Tags: xcom-enemy-within, xcom-long-war

Context of this question is under the current version of the Long War mod (b15f).

If at the soldier selection screen of a base defense mission, the player selects multiple officers, the highest ranking officer will be denoted as "Commanding Officer" (or similar wording).

On a normal mission, the commanding officer would be the only soldier with the command ability available during the mission. In this case, it is not guaranteed that the commanding officer will be selected (as 6 of the 12 will be chosen randomly).

If the soldier marked as commanding does not get selected, and one of the other officers does, will the active officer soldier have command available during the base defense mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently received a base defense mission in my current b15f3 campaign. It seems that the Command ability is not available if the Commanding Officer is not selected as an active soldier.

I selected 5 officers as a test. The soldier displayed as 'Commanding Officer' at the load out screen was not part of the troops that appeared in mission. Out of the multiple (lower ranked) officers that did appear in the mission, none of them had Command available.

Comment: I'll add - I suspect that the "commanding officer" may be the highest-grade officer *selected for the mission.*  By which I mean, at the end of the mission, 8 soldiers are fatigued (some are selected to serve as reinforcements if some of the first five die).  The highest ranking of those 8 should have command.